# Conflicto con GIT en mi macOs al cambiar de cuenta en github

Tags: git, github

Resulta que hace poco me cambie de cuenta en `github`, probé este comando para actualizar las cuentas dentro de `macOs`

```
git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

Pero sigue arrojando este error.

```
remote: Permission to BrianAlexanderzalaquett/WalletDive.git denied to 1brian.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/BrianAlexanderzalaquett/WalletDive.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Se me ocurre que debería desinstalar y volver a instalar nuevamente generando nuevas configuraciones, pero si alguien sabe de otra solución, quedare muy agradecido.

Saludos

Comment: Has probado de bajarte la clave ssh?

Comment: crea la clave ssh desde tu macOs de nuevo y añadela a tu perfil github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las variables de configuración `name`y/o `email` son importantes para las confirmaciones de cambios y solo son requeridas una sola vez, así que cambiar de cuenta de `github` en nada afecta la necesidad de reasignación de estas variables. Para el caso presente no es posible el acceso remoto al repositorio, seguramente por la no configuración de acceso, ésto debido al cambio de cuenta. En la página de configuraciones [settings](https://github.com/settings/profile), en el menú `Personal settings` se encuentra la opción [SSH and GPG keys](https://github.com/settings/keys), allí ingresará una nueva llave dando clic en el botón `New SSH key`, copiará la llave pública y la pegará allí. Para ver la clave se encuentra el comando

```sh
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Si desea reescribir o generar una nueva llave ejecute el siguiente comando

```sh
$ ssh-keygen -o -t rsa -b 4096 -C "email@example.com"
```

Comment: Resulta que no tenia clave ssh, a si que puse el primer comando que me diste, el cat... me mostro la clave y luego puse mis contraseñas como se debe. resulta que me arrojo la clave ssh con el nuevo mail, pero al intentar hacer push me arroja el mismo error....

Comment: Estara mal el procedimiento o algo que haya echo mal?

Comment: Cordial saludo, no entendí muy bien el procedimiento realizado. El primer comando `cat` se encarga de mostrar en consola la llave pública, si no arroja nada es que no se encuentra, en ese caso agrega el segundo comando para la generación de las llaves. Luego de ello ejecuta nuevamente el primer comando y copia de la consola lo que allí se imprimió, posterior lo pega en github. Ésto ya debe permitir realizar push sin autenticación, aún así en caso de no haber llave git solicitará usuario y password de github, ingresandolos debe haber permitido el push.

Comment: Me sigue arrojando el mismo error, tenga en cuenta que ya agregue la clave ssh, pero sigue habiendo conflicto, no me imagino que pueda ser. Saludos... si aclarar los pasos a seguir en orden seria suficiente.

Comment: Podría seguir los pasos que se encuentran en la [página de ayuda de Github](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/) y comentarme los resultados.

Comment: No tuve resultados positivos de los pasos a seguir, solo elimine la clave de internet de mi antigua cuenta, y la verdad nose si eso me ayude a sincronizar mi repositorio con mi actual cuenta..Quedara un ultimo paso por revisar? algún detalle?

Comment: Termine por borrar las claves de internet como me lo sugeriste. Al borrar el antiguo archivo de git en la carpeta del proyecto, me permitio hacer un nuevo git init, y con ayuda de Dios al momento de hacer push me pidio el nuevo usuario y password, con eso todo listo